# Nested Completable stops observer chain

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

I want to execute a `Completable` in `flatMap` and "map" it to a specific value I need. The subscribe block is never executed. Why?

I'm aware of the existence of `flatMapCompletable` and `andThen`, but these don't solve my problem. This code is also a little simplified, in my real code I need to apply more operators to the nested `Observable` (derived from `Completable`), so I really need the conversion to `Observable`.

```
disposables += myPublishSubject.withLatestFrom(myObservable).flatMap { (_, result) ->
    myCompletable()
        .toObservable<Unit>()
        .map { result } // Return result of "parent" observable after Completable completes
}.subscribe { result ->
    Timber.i("result: $result") // Not executed!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completables have no items thus when converted back to Observable, that Observable is also empty and thus never calls `map`. Use `andThen(Observable.just(result))`,

```
disposables += myPublishSubject.withLatestFrom(myObservable).flatMap { (_, result) ->
    myCompletable()
        .andThen(Observable.just(result))
}.subscribe { result ->
    Timber.i("result: $result") // Not executed!
}
```

or convert the `Completable` back to single with a default:

```
disposables += myPublishSubject.withLatestFrom(myObservable)
.flatMapSingle { (_, result) ->
    myCompletable()
        .toSingleDefault(result)
}.subscribe { result ->
    Timber.i("result: $result") // Not executed!
}
```